# order by group function with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
select round(avg(employees.salary)) as "Average salary",
count(1) as "Number of employees",
employees.department_id as "Department ID",
departments.department_name as "Department Name"
from employees, departments
where employees.department_id = departments.department_id
group by employees.department_id, departments.department_name
order by round(avg(employees.salary)) desc;
```

The returned result is not in the desired order. However, when trying to use alias "Average salary" or 1 the query works just as expected and desired.

The result of the mentioned query:

[image]

The result when I use an alias or number:

[image]

Why?

Comment: `round(avg(employees.salary))` and `"Average salary"` are just synonyms in the `order by` clause. You might want to provide a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: That's... weird. Reproducible in 19.3 with standard HR schema. It isn't completely ignoring the order-by, but it isn't working properly. (Same with ANSI joins, just to check; and without the round in the order-by...)

Comment: Stripping it back, the same thing happens with just the avg in the select and order-by clauses; unless you only group by one of ID and name, not both.. [Live SQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kag8bp54as0moyt3fu6lqfis1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, thats a bug.  We look for opportunities to eliminate the cost of group by, and in this case, something is going amiss.  You can hint around this as a workaround

```
SQL> select round(avg(employees.salary)) as "Average salary"
  2  from hr.employees, hr.departments
  3  where employees.department_id = departments.department_id
  4  group by employees.department_id, departments.department_name
  5  order by round(avg(employees.salary)) desc;

Average salary
--------------
          8956
          3476
         19333
          8601
          5760
          4150
         10154
          9500
         10000
          6500
          4400

11 rows selected.

SQL> select /*+ opt_param('_optimizer_aggr_groupby_elim', 'false')*/ round(avg(employees.salary)) as "Average salary"
  2  from hr.employees, hr.departments
  3  where employees.department_id = departments.department_id
  4  group by employees.department_id, departments.department_name
  5  order by round(avg(employees.salary)) desc;

Average salary
--------------
         19333
         10154
         10000
          9500
          8956
          8601
          6500
          5760
          4400
          4150
          3476

11 rows selected.
```